# Print a table inside a div with given row and column via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, html-table

I have two textfield and one button. When user clicked the button, It calls a function and print a table inside a div with given number of rows and columns.

You can see my code below, but this is not working as expected.

**HTML**

```
    Rows <input type="text" id="rows">
    Columns <input type="text" id="columns">

    <input type="button" value="Create Table" onClick="printTable();">

    <div id="box"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    function printTable()
    {
        var nRows=document.getElementById("rows");
        var nColumns=document.getElementById("columns");
        var spaceofDiv=document.getElementById("box");

        spaceofDiv.innerHTML=("<table border=1>");
        for(i=0; i<nRows.value; i++)
        {
            spaceofDiv.innerHTML=("<tr>");
            for(j=0; j<nColumns.value; j++)
            {    
                spaceofDiv.innerHTML=("<td width=50 height=50>&nbsp;");
            }
        }
        spaceofDiv.innerHTML=("</table>");     

    }
```

Comment: "this is not working as expected": what do you expect it to do? What do you get instead? I see you are new. Remember: the more details you give, the easier you will get a reply and an accurate answer.

Comment: Next time i will do a better explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some thing this. Use a avariable add all string in to it and then set innerhtml. Als oyou are not closing the `tr`

```
function printTable()
    {
        var nRows=document.getElementById("rows");
        var nColumns=document.getElementById("columns");
        var spaceofDiv=document.getElementById("box");
        var tableStr = "";
        tableStr =("<table border=1>");
        for(i=0; i<nRows.value; i++)
        {
            tableStr +="<tr>";
            for(j=0; j<nColumns.value; j++)
            {    
                tableStr +="<td width=50 height=50></td>&nbsp;";
            }
            tableStr +="</tr>"; 
        }
        tableStr  += "</table>"
        spaceofDiv.innerHTML=tableStr;     

    }
```

Comment: You might want to close the table cell elements as well.

Comment: I do it now. It's a mine bad habit

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember to

A) Close your table row and table cell elements

B) Concatenate the value of the table markup, as you are currently overwriting your changes with each assignment

```
    var markup = '';
    markup = "<table border=1>";
    for(i=0; i<nRows.value; i++)
    {
        markup += "<tr>";
        for(j=0; j<nColumns.value; j++)
        {    
            markup += "<td width=50 height=50>&nbsp;</td>";
        }
        markup += "</tr>";
    }
    markup = "</table>";     

    spaceofDiv.innerHTML = markup;
```

Comment: Thank's for your attention and your time!

Comment: Sorry. About to give you +1 but by mistake. My bad !